# What is the exact meaning that QED perturbative series is only asymptotic and eventually diverges at very high orders?

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics, renormalization, perturbation-theory, asymptotics

When I read paper PRB89, 235431 about the effective field theory of graphene, there is a statement that QED perturbative series is only asymptotic and eventually diverges at very high orders (e. g. the second paragraph in sec. II), which I cannot understand exactly.

It is known that QED is renormalizable. Thus, why the perturbative series diverge at the orders higher than 137. Please give me some refs, thank you.

Comment: We have a question about the physical meaning of the perturbation series being asymptotic and not convergent [here already](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/130154/50583). I'm not sure what *exactly* your question is, and if it is different from that one.

Comment: @ACuriousMind I have read your question and answers. The key point you concern about is radius of convergence. In the sense of the radius of convergence, I know the coupling constant must be small such as fine structure constant. Moreover, it can be found in answer that "this argument is strictly heuristical". Thus, I guess the author of current paper PRB89, 235431 want tell us that the  perturbative series would diverge ultimately, no matter what is coupling constant.